# How to update multiple documents in mongodb with Spring MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

Let's say I have multiple documents:

```
{
  "id":"id1",
  "name":"abc"
},
{
  "id":"id2",
  "name":"def"  
},
{
  "id":"id3",
  "name":"ghi"
}
```

Now I want to update doc who's name="abc" to name="xyz" and who's name="def" to name="uvw".
Is't possible to do that in a single query/update call? Since in my use-case I have thousands of documents that I want to update per call.